# Display port via usb type c not working

Tags: drivers, usb, display, dell

I have a dell latutude 5480 running ubuntu (had the same issues with 16 and 17 as well)

I have connected a dp monitor via usb type c, it did not work, i have tried to play with the connection and it worked for a moment, than i have used sudo apt get update, upgrade and it stopped again.

I have installed a fresh ubuntu 17 and it still does not work

The monitor is working perfectly when connected to another machine using the very same cable.

I am running

```
lspci -d ::0c03 -k
```

and getting

> 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI
>   Controller (rev 31)   Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI
>   Controller    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

I use

```
tail -f /var/log/kern.log
```

And connect and unplug the adapter, and see no reaction

I read that it probably means that i am missing a driver, but can't find any reference for how to install one...

Edit: 
when I use usb type c -> dvi cable with the same machine, os and monitor it works like a charm, does this mean that the usb port and driver are ok and the problem was the adaptor?

Comment: Does your Dell have Thunderbolt 3 over USB Type C?

Comment: HDMI/DisplayPort over USB-C seems to be a [mixed bag](https://askubuntu.com/a/902658/783023) at the moment.  Maybe you can get some help in the [vendor forums of Dell](https://www.dell.com/community/Sputnik/usbc-to-DisplayPort-does-not-work-on-Ubuntu-s-dell-xps-13/m-p/4759600) ?

Comment: it is a thunderbolt, and i do not understand what's helpful in that superuser link, care to elaborate?

Comment: It was just meant for information.  Removed since apparently it didn't help.  Just trying to find as much information as I can to help as I cannot find anything about drivers.

Comment: @Terrance - sorry friend! i did not try to say that the link is not informative, i just did not understand what you tried to show me and needed some more info, maybe you should re post it?

Comment: Can you post retailer link of adapter?

Comment: It's no worries.  I am really having a heck of a time finding anything about DP over USB-C.  A couple of things I stumbled across earlier mentioned kernel versions, but they also mentioned the Dell DA200 which is not what you're using.  One of my co-workers did tell me that it is new enough that Linux might not have support for the device for another possible 6 months or so.